# How to redirect back to the single post based on the id of that post after deleting a comment

Tags: php, sql

I am having an issue trying to go back to that specific page with a dynamic id. In this example, the id is 218 passed into a variable. I tried using the url encode method but it isn't still working

I have attached some screenshots about the page [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZurDK.png)

Here is the error I get because it does not display any id after hitting the delete button, However, the review gets deleted, but the page is not redirected to the specific post [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X5CU.png)

```
    <a href="single-property1.php?delete=<?php echo $review_id; ?>" class="mb-0 text-heading border-left border-dark hover-primary lh-1 ml-2 pl-2"><?php echo $list_id?> Delete</a>    
// I had to echo the $list_id to check if i could get the value, I kept getting the value as seen in the picture which is 218, but it doesnt output anything in the headers              

  // To delete
                    if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
                        $delete_post_id = $_GET['delete'];
                        $query = "DELETE FROM reviews WHERE review_id = {$delete_post_id}";
                        $delete_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                        // to check if that connection exists 
                        if (!$connection) {
                            die("QUERY FAILED" . mysqli_error($connection));
                        } else {
                        header("location: single-property1.php?p_id=".urlencode($list_id));
                        }
                    }
                  ?>

//the variable $list_id is what holds the id of the post, but when redirected, I am unable to get the id value
```

Comment: That's quite odd, I ran your code locally and it redirected as expected. Maybe you're replacing the value of $list_id somewhere before the ```if(isset($_GET['delete'])``` code?

Comment: I am not replacing the value . I even had to echo the list I’d value as seen in the screenshot just right beside the delete link after which I had the delete query